# How to enable tab completion in Scala's MainGenericRunner REPL (interactive interpreter)?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I've added a REPL (read eval print loop) to may Java project<sup>1</sup> which is build with maven. The [REPL can be started with a script](https://github.com/rtreffer/minidns/blob/d95b7f3afa6e4cc1f54adf286720215a03952152/repl#L15). The relevant parts are

```sh
declare -r GRADLE_CLASSPATH="$(gradle :minidns-repl:printClasspath --quiet |tail -n1)"

java \
    -Dscala.usejavacp=true \
    -classpath "${GRADLE_CLASSPATH}" \
    scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner \
    -i minidns-repl/scala.repl
```

This works so far. The only thing that is missing which would make the REPL perfect is **tab completion**. I know from Scala that it does support this.

How can I enable it for `MainGenericRunner`?

1: Feel free to test the REPL:

```
git clone https://github.com/rtreffer/minidns.git \
  && cd minidns \
  && ./repl`
```

Then perform a DNS query, e.g. `c.query("wikipedia.org", TYPE.A)`

Comment: Well it does it very poorly. For proper tab completion look at the https://lihaoyi.github.io/Ammonite/#Ammonite-REPL

Comment: I've just switched Ammonite REPL and tab completion works out of the box. See https://github.com/rtreffer/minidns/commit/1fe5fe1d73eadbf6d12cd2ce6576ad0e00ca9993 Please put this up as answer so you can collect your bounty :)

Comment: Ahh one second, I know get a error when trying to invoke a method: "Main.scala:11: Internal is renamed twice
import ammonite.repl.frontend.ReplBridge.repl.{"

Comment: See https://github.com/lihaoyi/Ammonite/issues/352

Comment: When you import import de.measite.minidns._ it imports 'repl' object after which ammonite fails. Either don't use wildcard imports or rename de.measite.minidns.repl, until ammonite is fixed.

Comment: Thanks @vitalii, now it works. Please put up an answer if you want to collect the bounty. :)

Comment: Scala REPL 2.11.8 completion is rewritten and superior. See the upcoming release notes https://github.com/SethTisue/make-release-notes/blob/release-notes-2.11.8/hand-written.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although current scala repl has autocompletion feature right now it is not working very well. (that's aside the [issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7898) mentioned by som-snytt).

If you need the working completions in repl you best bet would be [Ammonite REPL](https://lihaoyi.github.io/Ammonite/#Ammonite-REPL) which also has some more features then the standard repl.

**NOTE:** I haven't tested tab completions in 2.11.8, but it looks like they had been rewritten from scratch and are looking very promising.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [known issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7898) with the way `-i` is handled, that breaks completion.

There's also a fix pending, but I don't if it will get into 2.11.8, which also has an entirely [new completion feature.](https://github.com/SethTisue/make-release-notes/blob/release-notes-2.11.8/hand-written.md)